# Read a Binary Image with C++ and how .raw format is stored

Tags: c++, computer-vision, edge-detection

I have this problem, the binary image is stored in .raw format, the file can be opened with photoshop with 8bits and correct width and height together with 5 bytes header.  It is stated that the the first 4 bytes are for size(2 for rows and 2 for columns). The next byte is for the colordepth(255,graylevel). the rest are the intensities for each point. However, it seems that they are not stored in an order as from left to right and top to bottom.

May I know how is it stored so that I can manipulate the data?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are MANY raw formats: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format  including IIQ (Phase One), 3FR (Hasselblad), DCR, K25, KDC (Kodak), CR2 (Canon), ERF (Epson), MEF (Mamiya), MOS (Leaf), NEF (Nikon), ORF (Olympus), PEF (Pentax), RW2 (Panasonic) and ARW, SRF, SR2 (Sony) among others.  Some are variants on TIFF.

Comment: If Photoshop opens it correctly, write it out in some other lossless format like a .bmp, which is well documented.

Comment: @AndyG As stated, I can open it if I state the number of columns and rows correctly, as well as stating the 5 bytes header yet I don't quite understand how does Photoshop read that or how the data is aligned in the file.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Hi, the format is simply .raw not these stated format and its header is as stated, yet I don't know how the data is organized.

Comment: @user3113633: Unless the .raw extension is stored as ISO 12234-2 (http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=29377), you're out of luck because most digital camera manufacturers' .raw extensions remain undocumented so that they may sell you software (or get you to buy from a company that licenses the standard)